# Is the closure of an equicontinuous set (of $L_2[0,1]$) also equicontinuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

For context I need to show that an operator $A:L_2[0,1]\rightarrow L_2[0,1]$ is compact, for that I can show that $\overline{A[B_1(0)]}$ is compact. For that, by the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem, I need to show that it is both uniformly bounded and uniformly equicontinuous (the condition that it is closed comes trivially).

For the bounded condition, I just show that, for any $x\in B_1(0)$, I have that $||Ax||\leq C$ for some $C>0$ (basically just showing that $A$ is bounded). This means that $A[B_1(0)]\subset B_C(0)$, therefore, $\overline{A[B_1(0)]}\subset \overline{B_C(0)}$ and I show that it is bounded.

Now I show that $A[B_1(0)]$ is uniformly continuous. So I show that

$$\forall_{\epsilon >0}, \exists_{\delta>0}: \forall_{t_i,t_2\in [0,1]}, \forall_{x\in B_1(0)}, |t_2-t_1|<\delta \implies |Ax(t_2)-Ax(t_1)|<\epsilon$$

So far so good. Now I point out that $\overline{S}$ is basically just $S$ with its limit points, is it enough to show that $\overline{A[B_1(0)]}$ is equicontinuous?

Example: To show that $A=\int_0^1 K(s,t)x(s)ds$ is compact for $K:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous. (Is $K(s,t)=\frac{\cos(t-s)}{|t-s|^\frac{1}{5}}$ uniformly continuous?)

Comment: How does Arzela Ascoli apply to $L^2$?

Comment: For $L^p$ spaces you cannot apply Arzelà-Ascoli, instead you might want to use its variant [Fréchet-Kolmogorov](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_theorem) instead.

Comment: Your $K(s,t)$ at the end is not even defined everywhere on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ (i.e. not at $s=t$, so not even continuous, let alone uniformly continuous.

Comment: It looks to me like you are proving something stronger: that $A$ is actually compact as an operator $A : L^2[0,1] \to C[0,1]$.  If so then it is also compact as $A : L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$, by virtue of the fact that the inclusion of $C[0,1]$ into $L^2[0,1]$ is continuous.